# Macbook Pro won't start after restart (red charger icon)

Tags: mac, battery, startup, charge

So I just installed Flash and restarted my Mac, and now it won't start. It was working perfectly before that and I didn't drop it or anything.

The power cable works (tried it on another Mac) so it's not that.

When I press the power button I see the charger loading icon and it's red (like 2mm bar) then it takes 2 seconds and the screen is black. No sound what so ever. When I plug in the power cable I can see that it changes from no cable to cable plugged in, but it won't charge or start.

What can have happened and what to do? It's a 2 year old MacBook 15" retina.

Please help

Comment: Have you tried Verbose, Single User, or Safe mode? Have you run Apple Diagnostics?

Answer (score 3):

It is unlikely that the installation of Flash did anything to your power system, it is likely just a coincidence.

How long have you left the charger plugged in to the Mac? I would give it an hour, minimum, overnight is best.

Failing that try resetting the SMC:

`...Press Shift-Control-Option on the left side of the built-in keyboard, then press the power button at the same time. Hold these keys and the power button for 10 seconds`.

That is from https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295 Their article on resetting the SMC.

If *that* doesn't work it is possible your battery is dead, time to take it into an Apple store or other Mac repair shop.